# ckeditor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icons' of null

Tags: ckeditor

When trying to use ckeditor for the first time.  ckeditor works, but when I try to add imageupload and uploadloadwidget plugins then I get the error:
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icons' of null***

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing it?

```js
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('imageupload', '/ckeditor/plugins/imageupload/');
        CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('uploadwidget', '/ckeditor/plugins/uploadwidget/');
        CKEDITOR.replace('htmleditor', {
            htmlEncodeOutput: true,
            extraPlugins: 'imageupload,uploadwidget'

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are these the official plugins? Because there's no imageupload, but uploadimage. Did you copy them in your own server? Also, uploadwidget has dependencies for other plugins, which do not exist in the basic edition.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly take a look at this http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage and this http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html#uploading-dropped-and-pasted-images
for reference.

You'll have to setup the upload url and enable the uploadimage plugin in the configs like this:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
config.imageUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php?type=Images';

editor.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( evt ) {
    var fileLoader = evt.data.fileLoader,
        formData = new FormData(),
        xhr = fileLoader.xhr;

    xhr.open( 'PUT', fileLoader.uploadUrl, true );
    formData.append( 'upload', fileLoader.file, fileLoader.fileName );
    fileLoader.xhr.send( formData );

    // Prevented the default behavior.
    evt.stop();
}, null, null, 4 ); // Listener with a priority 4 will be executed before priority 5.
```

The docs has more info on this and how to handle different scenarios

Comment: @simon831 please refer to the ckeditor site for implementation. I provided the links to this

Answer (score 2):

Too late for the original poster, but I had this same problem and it turned out that I hadn't included the UploadWidget pluging that UploadImage was dependent on.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your path has pointed to a valid icon file, is it .ico? or .png? if not set your path to the valid image/icon file. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was based on @Daniel's response. I started looking for a reference to a plugin that was trying to load but was not installed.

I was not doing any image uploading but I was trying to add a plugin that I had not installed. Specifically, it was:
`extraPlugins: 'tableresize',`

I did not need `tableresize` so I just removed the `tableresize` from the `extraPlugins` line. I reloaded the page and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP Version from 7.4 to 7.3 or bellow