# CKEditor Plugin giving errors 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icons' of null'

Tags: ckeditor

I am just starting with CKEditor (latest version 4.5.7) using the cdn, wanting to use the plugin:

```
http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage
```

I have downloaded and extracted the files of that plugin to 'myplugins/uploadImage/'.

```
                <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'uploadImage', '/myplugins/uploadImage/', 'plugin.js' );
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                         extraPlugins: 'uploadImage'
                    } );                        
                </script>
```

CKEditor works without any plugins, but when I do the above to add the 'uploadImage' plugin, I am getting the following error in chrome console:

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icons' of null'

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: I'm also same, waiting for response...

Comment: Start a bounty? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258408/ckeditor-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-icons-of-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was based on this answer: [ckeditor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icons' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258408/ckeditor-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-icons-of-null)

I was not doing any image uploading but I was trying to add a plugin that I had not installed. Specifically, it was:
`extraPlugins: 'tableresize',`

I did not need `tableresize` so I just removed the `tableresize` from the `extraPlugins` line. I reloaded the page and the error was gone.